# Column ' ' in field is ambiguous

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, sql-update

Im working with MySQL in java.

I'm trying to update the 'owners' field in one of the tables 'regApartmentsTable', 'gardApartmentsTable', 'penthousesTable', which is empty, and corresponds to specific apartmentNum and street, and replace it with the string 'newOwners'.

In order to do that I've wrote the following code:

```
st=connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE regApartmentsTable,gardApartmentsTable,penthousesTable SET owners=? " +
                "WHERE owners=? AND apartmentNum=? AND street=?");
st.setString(1, newOwners);
st.setString(2, "");
st.setInt(3, apartmentNum);
st.setString(4, streetName+" "+buildingNum);
```

I include the 3 tables since I need to look in all of them. (The required apartment, which has no owners, and matches the apartmentNum and street, cannot be in more than one table, if it helps anyone).

But, when I try to run this code, I get a "Column 'owners' in field is ambiguous" error.
Any ideas how else should I write the SQL command ?
thanks ahead!

EDIT:
I didn't get a sufficient answer to my problem... Ok, I understood that the exception raises since 'owners' field is common in those three tables.
And yet, how do I solve the problem? I cannot add a prefix with the table's name since I do not know in which table I'm going to find the required apartment... If I knew so, I wouldn't have searched in 3 tables.

Comment: are you aware that you can only update one table on `UPDATE` with joins?

Comment: Im not sure I fully understand what you say, but I do not intend to update more than one table at all.

Comment: The error means that you have an `owners` column in more than one of the tables. You need to specify the appropriate table-name in front of `owners`, e.g. `regApartmentsTable.owners`. Alternatively you can use an alias to save typing, e.g. `regApartmentsTable AS a`, and then just: `a.owners` would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

The multiple tables UPDATE in MySQL is just a form of table join, using `regApartmentsTable.owners` and such.

You need a separate UPDATE for every table here, as a join is not what you intend for the update. Or make a base table.

```
str = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE regApartmentsTable SET owners=? " +
                "WHERE owners=? AND apartmentNum=? AND street=?");
str.setString(1, newOwners);
str.setString(2, "");
str.setInt(3, apartmentNum);
str.setString(4, streetName+" "+buildingNum);

str = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE gardApartmentsTable SET owners=? " +
                "WHERE owners=? AND apartmentNum=? AND street=?");
stg.setString(1, newOwners);
stg.setString(2, "");
stg.setInt(3, apartmentNum);
stg.setString(4, streetName+" "+buildingNum);

stp = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE penthousesTable SET owners=? " +
                "WHERE owners=? AND apartmentNum=? AND street=?");
stp.setString(1, newOwners);
stp.setString(2, "");
stp.setInt(3, apartmentNum);
stp.setString(4, streetName+" "+buildingNum);
```

Comment: Ok, but I do not know in which one of the tables the apartment is going to answer the requirements.... this didn't solve my problem..

Comment: Fine, as I think there is no other in-place solution (without changing the database), I have added the feasible solution.